# execute update return 1 but does not update

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I am trying to update my local sqlite table. 
My `executeUpdate()` returns 1 but does not update.
I couldnt add full runnable code because it needs to work with local database.

This is codeblock where I update table.

```
 protected int notGuncelle(int gelenId, String yeniNot) {
    int update = -1;

    try {
        update = st.executeUpdate("UPDATE notlar SET 'not' = " + "'yeniNot'"  + " WHERE id = " + gelenId);

        System.out.println(update);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        //Logger.getLogger(SQLiteFunctions.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("Not güncelleme hatası: " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    return update;

}
```

Now below code return -1 but works. I m really confused. I think it is because of the way of passing `yeniNot` variable to query. There is something wrong there but i dont know what.

```
protected int notGuncelle(int gelenId, String yeniNot) {
    int update = -1;
    System.out.println(yeniNot);
    try {
        PreparedStatement st = this.conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE notlar SET 'not' = ? WHERE id = ?");
        st.setString(1, yeniNot);
        st.setString(2, "" + gelenId);

        st.executeUpdate();
        //update = st.executeUpdate("UPDATE notlar SET 'not' = " + yeniNot + " WHERE id = " + gelenId);
        System.out.println(update);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        //Logger.getLogger(SQLiteFunctions.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("Not güncelleme hatası: " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    return update;

}
```

Comment: Make sure you are committing the transaction

Comment: I committd but nothing happened. Same again.

Answer (score 1):

OK i found the solution.

This must be replaced

```
 update = st.executeUpdate("UPDATE notlar SET 'not' = " + "'yeniNot'"  + " WHERE id = " + gelenId);
```

with this

```
update = st.executeUpdate("UPDATE notlar SET 'not' = + '"+yeniNot+"'" + " " + "WHERE id = " + gelenId);
```

`"'yeniNot'"` is wrong style of passing String parameter to query 
It should be like that >> `'"+yeniNot+"'`

Comment: I will strongly suggest to use the `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 0):

if you had set autocommit to false

```
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
```

then you have to commit manually by invoking method

```
        con.commit();
```

of course you can set autocommit to true then every statement will be treated as a single transaction

Comment: I tried tried both autocommit and this one . It does not work.